# Is it possible to create a shortcut to a file that is in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-android-api

I have asked this question so that they can respond that it is possible to create a shortcut for a file that is in the cloud, this access will be created in the device memory, what is the purpose of this: My application has integrated a function to upload a file to the cloud and then run it from a system application like player, gallery, among others, but without having to download anything, but from an application that is installed Installed on the device (nothing external). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [Create a shortcut to a file](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-create#create_a_shortcut_to_a_file). As mentioned,

> To create a shortcut instead of a file stored in Drive, use the [`files.create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) method of the API and make sure you set the MIME type `application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk`. Do not upload any content when creating the file.

However, for Google Drive Android API, you may want to check [Creating Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file) for more information.

Comment: One question: this method creates a shortcut to a gogole drive file in the device memory, right?